# Picture cannot be resolved to type

Tags: java

Any time I run one of the programs of mine with Picture in it, it does not compile without the error Picture cannot be resolved to a type. It will still run and complete the process but will show up with the error. I am using DrJava as my platform and in preferences I have the correct folder selected for my interactions pane which includes the Picture program, but it still comes up with the error.

I will provide each of the programs

```
import java.awt.*;
//checkerboard

public class Romeo_Class_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){

      Picture p = new Picture(800,500);
      Graphics g = p.getGraphics();
      g.setColor(Color.black);
      g.fillRect(250,100,300,300);
      g.setColor(Color.blue);
      g.fillRect(250,200,100,100);
      g.fillRect(350,100,100,100);    
      g.fillRect(350,300,100,100);     
      g.fillRect(450,200,100,100);
           p.repaint();
    }
}
```

After compiling this program it says

> File: F:\CS140\Class\Romeo_Class_1.java  [line: 8]
>   Error: Picture cannot be resolved to a type

However even with this error it will still run and provide the correct graphics.

Now if I were to actually compile and run the actual Picture file, it will not have errors, neither will the first one, but I do not want to have to manually compile and run the Picture file every single time I run a program that uses this.

Here is the Picture file

```
public class Picture extends SimplePicture  {
    public Picture () {
        super();  
    }

    public Picture(String fileName) {
        super(fileName);
    }

    public Picture(int width, int height) {
        super(width,height);
    }

    public Picture(Picture copyPicture) { 
        super(copyPicture);
    }
}
```

This Picture program is located in the folder Picture classes which as I stated I have in the preferences selected in my interactions pane.

Does anyone have a solution to avoid this error rather than just manually running the Picture program before each time I use a program

Comment: Did you put `Picture.java` on the compiler's classpath (if you don't know what I'm talking about look it up in the compiler's documentation, hint: `-cp` or `--classpath`)? Did you put your classes into packages (you normally should) and if they are in different ones, did you import `Picture`?

Comment: I went to the interactions pane in preferences and for the interactions working directory i put in the Pictureclasses folder which has the Picture.Java in it. In the compiler options in the preferences I do not see anywhere that I can add the folder or a specific file.

Comment: I ended up fixing it I believe by as you are saying adding the same pathway that I had in the interactions pane, but as an extra class pathway. I do not know why it had to be in there twice, but it seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: You'd have to look at your IDE's documentation for that info. Note that compiler (`javac` command) and runtime (`java` command) both need a classpath and those might be different but could also be the same. I'd guess your "interactions working directory" handles the runtime classpath only.